# Separating User Picture from Submitted by date in Node

Tags: nodes, theming

on my node pages (drupal 7) the user picture is displayed along with the submitted by date. I'd like to separate them somehow so I can style them separately.

Anyone know a great way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) Module

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

Watch the [screencasts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7E361A55994F1648) to see it all in action!

Comment: thanks. When you configure a display for a node does it require that the node take up 100% of the width of the page? In my zen responsive layout I had one region (the node content gets put here) taking up 80% of the page (centered) and another region ON TOP OF IT, to the right (a navigation region)...but when I make the node a display using display suite it makes the whole navigation region go down underneath the node. I can't seem to make it come back up again unless I remove the display.

Comment: `does it require that the node take up 100% of the width of the page?` nope. For example, try doing the same with display suite using the default drupal theme and it shouldn't affect your right or left regions. Not sure why display suite is causing your right region to drop down. Highlight both (the node and nav region) and right mouse click and inspect the elements with your browser. Perhaps you need to increase the width of the div that is wrapping everything.

Comment: there is probably a code your theme .css that says 900px; or some big number, which controls the width of entire thing. so just increase it and hopefully should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "user" you mean specifically the author of current node, there are two pieces to look at:

1) The byline: Modifying the byline is straightforward in [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) and/or [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7).

In `template_preprocess_node()`, modify `$variables['submitted']` to be whatever you want it to be.

Here's a quick example,

```
$variables['submitted'] = t('Posted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $some_variable, '!datetime' => $some_other_variable));
```

2) The picture: In `node.tpl.php` you can easily control where the user picture and the byline printout by using the `$user_picture` and `$submitted` variables.

Here's a quick example,

```
<div class="user-picture"><?php print $user_picture; ?></div>
<div class="byline"><?php print $submitted; ?></div>
```

Lastly, if you want to modify the markup used for `$user_picture`, create and modify [user-picture.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-picture.tpl.php/7) in your theme.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developer and don't want to use heavy modules use `template_preprocess_node($vars)` function.
Use dpm to display variables and node values. From there you can easily extract image and assign it to new variable.

like

```
$var['image_only'] = <the image part>
```

Then you can use you newly defined variable in your node.tpl.php

```
print $image_only
```

Comment: There is no such a thing as `hook_node_preprocess` in D7. Check the Drupal API at http://api.drupal.org.

Comment: sorry - It was a typo, I meant hook_preprocess_node

Comment: You probably mean `template_preprocess_node()`?

Comment: yes, in drupal 7 hook can be called in themes as well like hook_form_alter that is why I added the word hook instead of template - thanks for the correction.